# ArcObjects access to ArcMap's Geoprocessing Results

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, .net, results-window

Is it possible to get ArcObjects access to the geoprocessing results that show up in the geoprocessing Results window in ArcMap?

I'm looking to remove results from geoprocessing operations that are run as part of a custom .Net addin.

Comment: Not sure how to directly manipulate that dockable window, but you could try not writing to it in the first place. Explore the property loghistory on igeoprocessor?

Comment: Yeah, I tested that, and unfortunately loghistory only affects an xml file that gets written locally into the user's `AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.6\ArcToolbox\History` folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than removing the results, I controlled whether or not to add the results in the first place with `IGeoProcessor2.AddToResults`

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//002n000000tq000000